# How to contract the square roots in the numerator and the denominator of the given function?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, parametric-functions

I have complicated function `g[s1,s2,Ss,t1,t2,m]` with the numerator containing only the summands with the square root factor. Its main part coincides with the full square root of the denominator of g. However, they doesn't cancel each other, within Mathematica. Precise form of these factors are

```
Sqrt[(-s2 + Ss + t1) (m^2 - s2 + t1 - t2) (m^2 t1 - s2 t2)]
```

in the numerator,

```
Sqrt[(m^4 t1 - m^2 (s2 (t1 + t2) + t1 (t2 - t1)) + s2 t2 (s2 - t1 + t2))]
```

in the denominator. They must cancel each other up to the multiplier in the numerator. But this doesn't happen. The command `Simplify[g[...]]` doesn't work. The command `FullSimplify` doesnt work also.

How to make Mathematica cancel these square roots?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `FullSimplify[expr, TransformationFunctions->{Automatic, PowerExpand}]`. First your expression:

```
expr = Sqrt[(-s2+Ss+t1) (m^2-s2+t1-t2) (m^2 t1-s2 t2)] /
       Sqrt[(m^4 t1-m^2 (s2 (t1+t2)+t1 (t2-t1))+s2 t2 (s2-t1+t2))];
```

Then, [`FullSimplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify):

```
FullSimplify[
    expr,
    TransformationFunctions->{Automatic,PowerExpand}
]
```

> I Sqrt[s2 - Ss - t1]

However, note the following [comment](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerExpand#6693) from the documentation:

> The transformations made by PowerExpand are correct in general only if c is an integer or a and b are positive real numbers.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me... It only separates the multipliers inside the root.

Comment: @JohnTaylor Then you should provide an example where it doesn't work.

Comment: @Carl Woll Could you please kindly comment, why in this case `FullSimplify` works, while `Simplify` does not?

Answer (score 2):

Try also the following. Here is your expression:

```
 expr = Sqrt[(-s2 + Ss + t1) (m^2 - s2 + t1 - t2) (m^2 t1 - s2 t2)]/
 Sqrt[(m^4 t1 - m^2 (s2 (t1 + t2) + t1 (t2 - t1)) + 
    s2 t2 (s2 - t1 + t2))];
```

Let us put the both expressions under the same radical:

```
    expr /. Sqrt[a_]/Sqrt[b_] -> Sqrt[a/b] // Simplify
(*  Sqrt[-s2 + Ss + t1]   *)
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

Mathematica treats all values by default as complex. If this is the case, you cannot cancel numerator and denominator. If square roots are real, you have to tell this to Mathematica, for example like this

```
$Assumptions=(-s2+Ss+t1)(m^2-s2+t1-t2)(m^2 t1-s2 t2)>0&&
(m^4 t1-m^2 (s2 (t1+t2)+t1 (t2-t1))+s2 t2 (s2-t1+t2))>0;
expr = Sqrt[(-s2+Ss+t1) (m^2-s2+t1-t2) (m^2 t1-s2 t2)] /
Sqrt[(m^4 t1-m^2 (s2 (t1+t2)+t1 (t2-t1))+s2 t2 (s2-t1+t2))];
FullSimplify[expr]
```